# Exporting a markdown file with inline PlantUml as a single SVG file

Tags: svg, visual-studio-code, markdown, plantuml

Our orginization uses markdown files with embedded PlantUml. We're trying to export the full markdown file to a single .svg file so we can view it on a third-party application. The [`plantuml`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml) VSCode plugin can export each embedded uml diagram to its own file, but doesn't appear to have an option to export the entire markdown to a new format.

**Example**

I would like this markdown diagram

````
## Read
```plantuml
@startuml
ClassA -> ClassB: Read done (location)
@enduml
```

## Write
```plantuml
@startuml
ClassC -> ClassD: Write done (location)
@enduml
```

## Etc...
````

to be exported to a .svg file that looks something like this:

[image: I just want a single file that looks like this.]

(This is a screenshot from Visual Studio, so ignore colors/fonts that may be different than a rendered .svg.)

I want the headers to be included as a part of the .svg, not just the class diagrams.

Comment: From your question it is not clear to me if you just want the diagrams saved to a file, when you render the markdown or if you want to be able to view the diagram in a bitbucket review. In the latter case you should make sure, that when you view the File.md (full, not just parts), bitbucket does render the markdown and the embedded plantuml

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a tendency to be too verbose; I'll edit the question to be a more direct.

Comment: Well what you can do is generate an html with the diagram embedded, then XSLT transform the output html to an SVG. The result then will be one SVG with headings and diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be related (https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/684), which embeds PlantUML diagrams in the HTML.

Starting from Markdown All in One v3.0.0, you can export Markdown file to HTML which looks exactly the same as inside VSCode. In your case, just install both extensions (PlantUML and MAIO).